# localhost doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, wampserver

I'm trying to solve out my problem since more than a week, but with no results until now.
When I try to open `localhost/phpmyadmin`, or any php file, I get on this message:

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage ".

The same happens with Mozilla; no errors, but the page keeps loading without answer.

*My configuration*

```
Windows 7 32bit
Wampserver 2.2D ( all services are running ) green status,  server online
```

*My hosts file*

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

IIS is stopped, but I don't think it's a problem with port 80.

I tried going directly to 127.0.0.1, it didn't work.

I will appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: By any chance do you have skype on? By default it takes up port 80 and thus you have to firstly uncheck that setting, restart the skype and only then apache is able to be launched properly. Just a wild guess tho :)

Comment: Go to skype option menu and disable this option. File -> Options -> Connection -> Uncheck "Use port 80 as an alternative for..."

Comment: go to cmd and type netstat -an and check for port 80 if its linsening or not if port 80 is listening then shut down wamp and try again and if still listening then some other application like skype may be using it

Comment: Don't use IE, please. And it's called Firefox not Mozilla!

Comment: not skype, is already unchecked " use port 80 as an alternative ....." thanks for your help.

Comment: @jadkik94 Mozilla was a browser once so be careful when saying that.

Comment: Does this problem occur if you are not viewing a PHP address?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your firewall authorizations...

I had same problem; I have since added `wampserver` as authorized program to my firewall and, as above, stopped IIS services in control panel/admistrative tools.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you have IIS on, stop it.

Go to `cpanel` and search administrative tools, component services, services (local), and scroll  to the `w`'s to find and stop:

```
World wide web publishing service
```

and

```
Web deployment agent service (something like that)
```

Good luck.

Comment: It is recommended not to include a signature since it the author is displayed below.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem, a lot of research and analysis but nothing helped. Finally I came across UwAmp which works like a charm for me ever since then. Try it out:

http://www.uwamp.com/

It also supports multiple versions of PHP which you can switch by single click anytime you want.

[image]

Comment: thnak you for your help, but i wanna find exactely what's the problem, should be working, everything is fine, so why it's not working?

Comment: thanks everyone is working now, it was port 80 causing the problem